# Group by and Concatenate Json rows with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with multiple rows/records with a different json value. I would like to group by and concatenate those into a final single row, as part of a select query

```
Id   Col
1    {'a': 1}        
1    {'b': 2} 
2    {'c': 3} 
2    {'d': 4} 
2    {'e': 5}
```

Desired Output

```
Id   Col
1    {'a': 1, 'b': 2}        
2    {'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

Comment: specify where is the table hosted

Comment: tag the database you are using

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `sql-server`,try the following:

```
CREATE table #temp( Id int,  Col varchar(100))
Insert into #temp values
(1,'{''a'': 1}')      
,(1,'{''b'': 2}')
,(2,'{''c'': 3}')
,(2,'{''d'': 4}')
,(2,'{''e'': 5}')

SELECT DISTINCT id,
          '{' 
         + STUFF((
                  SELECT ',' + Replace(Replace(col,'{',''),'}','')
                  FROM #temp as t1
                  WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                  FOR XML PATH('')
                  ), 1, 1, '')  
         +'}' AS col 
FROM #temp as t2

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, CONCAT('{',STRING_AGG(REPLACE(REPLACE(Col,'{',''),'}',''),','),'}') AS COL
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2832de9dd3a43a504b1df3158453ffae)

Comment: Col would then be a text column, could it be possible to restore the concatenated type back to json?

Comment: Table information does not change, it is displayed only in this format. use "select * from table". table data not changes

Comment: Looks like I am not able to access keys and values in my query of the above concatenated output, looks like it's not json

Comment: I displayed it in the format you want, in which case your data is not Json